# Passing on an out parameter

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, out

Is there a way to pass on an out parameter?
I want the out parameter to not be set in the function itself, but to be set in a function I call.

I'm unsure if I just got the syntax wrong. Here is what I tried:

```
bool func1(out int additionalReturn)
{
    //sample code
    additionalReturn = 0;
    return true;
}
bool func2(out int additionalReturn)
{
    return func1(additionalReturn);
}
```

Comment: I found the answer while typing the question and will answer it myself now

Comment: FWIW [there's a checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKY0b.png) specifically for this when asking a question so you can use so you can post your Q&A together in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `out` in the calling function allows this. The syntax is like this:

```
bool func1(out int additionalReturn)
{
    //sample code
    additionalReturn = 0;
    return true;
}
bool func2(out int additionalReturn)
{
    return func1(out additionalReturn);
}
```